# how to display word document in a web page?

Tags: java, html, ms-word

I am trying to display all type of files like PDF,ppt, word document, mp3,mp4 on web page when user clicks particular file. All the files are displayed using JSF and front end am using jQuery. I am able to display PDF using object tag but same doesn't work for word documents. Can anyone suggest me how to display word document and ppt files on web page?

Comment: Use HTML5LightBox
http://html5box.com/html5lightbox/

Comment: you mean opening office docs embedded in the browser (requires office installed in the client machine) or a html version of them (requires explicit convertion from the native format to html)?

Comment: Posting some code would help.

Comment: I used object tag for PDF like this.. <object data="sample.pdf" type="application/pdf"> alt: <a href="sample.pdf">download file</a> </object>.  Similarly I tried for word document by changing type to application/msword but it isn't displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to convert **Microsoft Office Documents** to html and show them in a web page just like **Google docs**.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a servlet, for PDF the code is like this,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = null;
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
try {

    // Public user guide
    String fileName = "MyFile.pdf";


    bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
    bufferedInputStream.read(data);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(servletOutputStream);
    bufferedOutputStream.write(data);

} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error(e);
} finally {

    if (bufferedInputStream != null) {
        bufferedInputStream.close();
    }

    if (bufferedOutputStream != null) {
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
    }

    if (servletOutputStream != null) {
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

}

For word just change the

```
response.setContentType("application/doc");
```